# How to install arduino-1.0.3-linux32.tgz?

Tags: installation, compiling, install-from-source

Can't `./configure` after I `tar`'ed Linux version from here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: Edit your question with the output from ./configure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly do you mean when you say that you can not run `./configure`?

It does not run, or it produces an error message?

Anyway, there are better ways to install arduino in Ubuntu. Please see http://playground.arduino.cc//Linux/Ubuntu.

*If you still want to install (run) from the tgz file, please see the end of this answer. That part was added later on.*

If you are impatient, press `Ctrl-Alt-T`. This will give you the command terminal.

Then type,

```
apt-cache search arduino
```

Press `Enter`.

After running the above, you will get a screen like this,

[image]

and then run,

```
sudo apt-get install arduino*
```

This is supposed to give something like,

[image]

Press Y and then Enter. Things should go all right from this point. It went fine for me.

**Added Later On, "For Installation from the tgz File"**

Download the tgz file from http://arduino.googlecode.com/files/arduino-1.0.3-linux32.tgz

Unpack the file

```
tar xvzf arduino-1.0.3-linux32.tgz
```

Move to the extracted directory

```
cd arduino-1.0.3
```

Run the shell script in that directory

```
./arduino
```

It ran perfectly in my machine, Ubuntu 12.04

[image: Arduino 1.03]

Comment: i need 1.0.3 version, not 1.0.1

Comment: @user83171 No problem, please see the end of my answer above. I have added a part later on.

Comment: Why was this upvoted? He's asking how to install it, not run it. Just running it from your home directory doesn't work as a lot of third party tools, like `ino`, expect it to be installed to a standard location like `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share/arduino`, etc. Just extracting the tarball and running the binary is not "installing" it.

Comment: @cerin It was upvoted by others since they found something of merit in the answer. And if you had time to read the complete answer, you will find that it covered *all* the ways of installing 
arduino. It does not matter whether running from home directory works or does not work for other tools, it worked for the tool under consideration. Perhaps you would like to notice the accepted button as well.

Comment: @Masroor, Sorry, I meant no offense, but the Op is clearly new, and accepted this answer because it was the only one. The correct solution is to copy or symlink the files to the appropriate directories.

Comment: @Cerin Yes, definitely your suggestion points me to a better direction. But, that would make her life more difficult. Anyway, as they, the accepted answer is not always the best answer. And as you pointed out, there was only one answer.